# Redirect .htaccess based on browser language and utm parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking for a way in `.htaccess` to redirect visits coming from GMB, if two conditions match:

- URL contains the parameter `?utm_source=gmb`

  AN example:

  `https://example.com/?utm_source=gmb&utm_medium=organic&utm_content=listing&utm_campaign=1`
- browser language is Portuguese (`pt`, `pt-pt` or `pt-br`)

Then to redirect to the Portuguese page is only needed to add `&lang=pt-pt` at the end of the URL since the site is using WPML with language as a parameter.

All the other requests, without `?utm_source=gmb`, I prefer to not redirect, to avoid indexation problems on SERPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following in `.htaccess` using mod_rewrite, however, note the caveats that follow:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check for "utm_source=gmb" anywhere in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)utm_source=gmb(?:$|&)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt(|-pt|-br)
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?lang=pt-pt [QSA,R,L]
```

> add `&lang=pt-pt` at the end of the URL

Note that this adds `lang=pt-pt` at the *start* of the query string and the remaining query string is appended (`QSA` flag). The order shouldn't matter, but this can be added at the end if you really require it (although it is not the "natural way" to do it).

However, this has a number of caveats regarding the language detection:

- It is not possible to determine the language "accurately" here.
- This *assumes* that the "primary" language is defined first in the `Accept-Language` HTTP header. Whilst this is common, this is not guaranteed.
- This doesn't tell you what language the user is actually using, just that `pt` is an *accepted* language by the browser. There is no way to determine the "actual" language being used here.
- Consequently, "redirecting" the user based on (basic) language detection is generally a bad idea.